# Why are the Tags not in alphabetical order ?

Tags: discussion

As a newcomer I need to look in various mixed up boxes with no logical order .Why not have a switch to create alphabetical access to new information ?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77808/does-it-matter-the-order-you-tag-your-question And I concur, this is a perfect question about the site - so it should be over on meta.

Answer (score 2):

There is a very logical order to the tags. The tags that appear first are the most popular and used most often. It's so when a user looks at a question they are more likely to see a tag that they know if the can answer the question or not or even want to look at the question or not.

With only up to 5 tags being on a question, the sorting isn't too important and either way would most likely be ok. However, one drawback that alphabetically sorting can lead is having tags that are never used being much more prominent than tags used all the time. For example, if we were to tag alphabetically [accent](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/accent) [guitar](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/guitar) [rhythm](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rhythm) on a question, the most popular tag on the site that may be a deciding factor to whether or not someone looks at the questions is sandwiched in the middle of the tags and on a quick read may be glossed over.

When you look at tags on the tag page you have the option of [sorting alphabetically](https://music.stackexchange.com/tags?tab=name), but it's not extremely practical for searching for what you want.

Answer (score 1):

A quick follow up to Dom's post.

One of the great ways Stack Exchange uses tags is that you don't need to hunt around for one that fits best. Just start typing the main topic of your question and the most common tags will automagically appear. For me this works way better than any other I have seen.

When browsing to find information, again, I don't need to look alphabetically. I either search all posts by age to get the newest stuff, or I use the word describing exactly what I want, eg [fingerstyle](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fingerstyle)